# How to transverse Upward through MySQL prepared statement to calculate Hierarchial Commissions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

## Update ** :

I changed the title of the question to better suit the overall need. I currently have a single table with my seller id's, their respective parent id, their commission level, the sum of the products they have sold and the total commission for those products (calculated in a case statement because commissions vary by product); but the issue I continue to run into is this:

I am unable to then transverse up the results from my query and calculate the sub-commissions every seller should receive as a result of their downline sellers (sellers they have brought on board at commission levels below them).

---

## Original Post:

I have a script which currently "works" but is nearly 3600 lines of code and makes well over 50 database calls within a single script. From my experience, there is no way to really "loop" the script and minimize it because each call to the database is a subquery of the ones before based on referral ids.

Perhaps I can give a very simple example of what I am trying to accomplish and see if anybody has experience with something similar.

In my example, there are three tables:

## Table 1 - Sellers

```
ID       |   Comm_level   |   Parent
-----------------------------------
1        |        4       |   NULL
2        |        3       |   1
3        |        2       |   1
4        |        2       |   2
5        |        2       |   2
6        |        1       |   3
```

Where ID is the id of one of our sales agents, comm_level will determine what his commission percentage is for each product he sells, parent indicates the ID for whom recruited that particular agent.
In the example above, 1 is the top agent, he recruited two agents, 2 and 3. 2 recruited two agents, 4 and 5. 3 recruited one agent, 6. NOTE: An agent can NEVER recruit anybody equal to or higher than their own level.

## Table 2 - Commissions

```
Level    |    Item 1    |     Item 2     |    Item 3
-----------------------------------------------------
4        |      .5      |       .4       |      .3    
3        |      .45     |       .35      |      .25    
2        |      .4      |       .3       |      .2    
1        |      .35     |       .25      |      .15
```

This table lays out the commission percentages for each agent based on their actual comm_level (if an agent is at a level 4, he will receive 50% on every item 1 sold, 40% on every item 2, 30% on every item 3 and so on.

## Table 3 - Items Sold

```
      ID     |      Item
   ---------------------
       4     |     item_1
       4     |     item_2
       1     |     item_1
       2     |     item_3
       6     |     item_2
       1     |     item_3
```

This table pairs the actual item sold with the seller who sold the item.

When generating the commission report, calculating individual values is very simple. Calculating their commission based on their sub_sellers however is very difficult.

In this example, Seller ID 1 gets a piece of every single item sold. The commission percentages indicate individual sales or the height of their commission.

For example:

When seller ID 6 sold one of item_2 above, the tree for commissions will look like the following:

-ID 6 - 25% of cost(item_1)

-ID 3 - 5% of cost(item_1) - (30% is his comm - 25% comm of seller id 6)

-ID 1 - 10% of cost(item_1) - (40% is his comm - 30% of seller id 3)

This must be calculated for every agent in the system from the top down (hence the DB calls within while loops throughout my enormous script).

Anybody have a good suggestion or samples they may have used in the past?

## EDIT TO COMMISSION STRUCTURE

Note: commissions in this example are residual, meaning if a seller onboards a customer in month 1, he/she will receive the same commission for that customer until they are no longer a subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Use abstractions (functions and classes) to hide the database access. This allows you to be more concise when writing the algorithm for calculating commissions. Furthermore it allows you to reuse results from earlier database queries. In the end, one loop over the Items Sold table should be enough, filling in the commissions of the actual seller and all ancestors. Ideally, each seller would be read from the database only once, either up front or on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

this might help get you started...

```
-- TABLES

drop table if exists seller;
create table seller
(
seller_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
comm_level tinyint unsigned default 0,
parent_seller_id int unsigned default null,
key (parent_seller_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into seller (comm_level, parent_seller_id) values
(4,null),
 (3,1),
 (2,1),
    (2,2),
    (2,2),
        (1,3);

-- STORED PROCEDURES

drop procedure if exists seller_commissions_hier;
delimiter #

create procedure seller_commissions_hier
(
in p_seller_id int unsigned,
in p_start_date date,
in p_end_date date
)
proc_main:begin

declare done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare dpth smallint unsigned default 0;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

create temporary table hier(
 parent_seller_id int unsigned, 
 seller_id int unsigned not null, 
 depth smallint unsigned not null default 0,
 comm_level tinyint unsigned not null default 0,
 sales decimal(10,2) not null default 0,
 commission decimal(10,2) not null default 0
)
engine = memory;

-- step1. work out the hierarchy with sales and commission set to 0

insert into hier select parent_seller_id, seller_id, 0, comm_level, 0 as sales, 0 as commission
 from seller where seller_id = p_seller_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not done do

    if exists( select 1 from seller s inner join hier on s.parent_seller_id = hier.seller_id and hier.depth = dpth) then

        insert into hier 
            select s.parent_seller_id, s.seller_id, dpth + 1, s.comm_level, 0, 0 from seller s
            inner join tmp on s.parent_seller_id = tmp.seller_id and tmp.depth = dpth;

        set dpth = dpth + 1;            

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = dpth;

    else
        set done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

-- step 2. update the hier table with sales totals for period you are interested in for each seller (to do)

-- (hint: use a derived table to calculate total sales for period grouped by seller_id and join back to hier for the update)

-- step 3. work out commissions based on sales and comm_level for each seller (to do)

-- (sure you can work this out)

-- step 4. output the results

select 
 s.seller_id,
 p.seller_id as parent_seller_id,
 hier.depth,
 hier.comm_level,
 hier.sales,
 hier.commission
from 
 hier
inner join seller s on hier.seller_id = s.seller_id
left outer join seller p on hier.parent_seller_id = p.seller_id
order by
 hier.depth, hier.seller_id; 

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

-- TESTING

call seller_commissions_hier(1, now() - interval 1 month, now());

call seller_commissions_hier(2, now() - interval 1 month, now());
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I actually storyboarded near the same suggestions you had but the issue I am facing is not even necessarily related to populating the hier table with sales/commission data on an individual level, but then how to cycle through and calculate the additional commission a seller would receive if he/she has downline (recruited) sellers under them.

Comment: ah - you might need an additional temporary hierachy to help compute that... will have a think but will be afk for a while :)

Comment: agreed. I have the table laid out exactly how I feel I need it to this point (all of our ideas combined with total sales and total individual commission listed out by agent) but it is tricky to build  script to transverse back up the tree calculating the sub-commissions as necessary. I'll keep toying around but if you have any suggestions, much appreciated. Also - shot you an email basically regarding this same concept - hadn't heard back!

Comment: @JM4 - sorry bit slow checking emails given the festive season - will take a look... :)